# preg_match rule for utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-match

what pregmach rule i must use for full_name field?
i want user input only character and not html or php code value and space between 3 to 11 character
i can use:

```
<?php
if (preg_match("%^[A-Za-z0-9-_]{3,10}$%", $_REQUEST['usr'])) {
//do something like 
mysql_query('insert into user(name) values(this field)');
//damn what is this for: It does not meet our quality standards.!!!
//i must insert more code? i dont have ! let me go !
}
else{
//do something else!
die('get out !:D');
}
?>
```

but with this user cant input UTF-8 characters like "مسیح ارسطوئی"
so what preg_match rule i must use  for UTF-8 ?
or what other code like preg_match i can use ?
I WANT USER JUST Can insert characters not <>{}[] or $%^&*
between 3 to 10 character !!!
thanks

Comment: Take a look at Unicode mode and character classes for regexes.

Comment: If they can only use english characters (based on your regex), then why would they be allowed to input "مسیح ارسطوئی"? That logic here makes 0 sense.

Comment: this is my question: what pregmach rule i must use for full_name field?

Comment: Yes, that's what you stated. You want only letters A thru Z (upper and lower case). Arabic letters are not included.

Works as designed. What is your problem?

Comment: I think what you want is only alphabetic characters but in all the world's character sets, is that correct?

Comment: [Unicode Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). You should be able to use this in php with the `u` modifier on your pattern.

Comment: yes what preg match rule i must use for utf-8 character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give "0", cos `مسیح ارسطوئی` is not containing only 3-10 chars;

```
$x = preg_match('~^([\pL]{3,10})$~u', 'مسیح ارسطوئی');
echo $x ? 1 : 0;
```

But this gives a result in your case;

```
preg_match('~([\pL]+)~u', 'مسیح ارسطوئی', $m);
print_r($m);

Array
(
    [0] => مسیح
    [1] => مسیح
)
```

See more details here: [PHP: Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

Comment: Replace [\pL] with [-_\pL\pM\pN], where \pN are numbers and \pM allows for diacritics and other combining marks. \pL alone will fail many valid usernames.

Answer (score 2):

Use `u` modifier like this:

```
preg_match('/pattern_with_unicode_symbols/u');
```

This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8.

and use "\x{2460}" syntax to define utf-8 character

Comment: if(preg_match("/([\p{L}\p{N}]{3,10})/u",$name) work but user can insert{}<> and more than 10 charts

Comment: `/^your_pattern$/u` means check whole subject

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/#(\pL*)/u', 'this is #مثال text', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

'u', '\pL': strings are treated as UTF-8.